# SQL Catching a warning thrown by remote procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, warnings

I have an issue where I call a stored procedure from a linked server and it times out. However I have no good way of catching this. Though it occurs rarely I am wondering if there is any way to catch this particular warning:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "serverName" returned message "Query timeout expired".

Unfortunatly warnings aren't caught by try/catch and MS does have an open issue that this should be an error: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/337043/no-error-raised-when-a-remote-procedure-times-out

I don't want to increase the timeout property, and I know I can do something like:

```
Declare @ret int
select @ret =  4417
Exec @ret=Server.DB.dbo.RemoteSP
```

If @ret is null afterwards it means the call failed, however it does not tell me exactly what the cause was. Is there anyway to essentially catch that warning? What are the best practices in for remote procedure calls error handling?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get this information.  The typical such failure is that the connection closes, which means that there would be no way to send results back.  You might combine your method of looking for a NULL return value with perusing logs on the remote server to get an idea of what happened.

Comment: In my experience using a linked server is seldom best practice to begin with.  Is there no other way to extract and correlate the data you need?

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019 there is still no way to properly catch SQL Server remote timeout errors.

It applies both to remote SP calls and constructs like `execute ('select 1') at REMOTESQLSERVER`.

As per [comment from N.Nelu](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b876cf7a-4810-4bbd-9e04-4dd9f56c60c6/job-step-successful-but-linked-server-timeout-means-it-actually-fails?forum=sqltools):

[Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) state under "Errors Unaffected by a TRY...CATCH Construct".

**Errors Unaffected by a TRY...CATCH Construct**

TRY...CATCH constructs do not trap the following conditions:

- Warnings or informational messages that have a severity of 10 or
  lower.
- Errors that have a severity of 20 or higher that stop the SQL Server Database Engine task processing for the session. If an error
  occurs that has severity of 20 or higher and the database connection
  is not disrupted, TRY...CATCH will handle the error.
- **Attentions, such as client-interrupt requests or broken client connections.**
- When the session is ended by a system administrator by using the KILL statement.

Connect link you have provided is dead but you still can vote to fix this *feature* [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32894512-no-error-raised-when-a-remote-procedure-times-out). See also this [excellent article on SQL Error handling](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Appendix1.html) under *4.3 Query Timeout on Linked Servers*.